# how to avoid injecting same dependency in multiple components

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 7 for my application.
I am injecting same dependency in multiple components in constructor(---).
can i inject some where in super class/component and reuse it?..
Please let me know if any one know the best solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the same injections, you can use an abstract component and use `Injector`.

```
export abstract class BaseComponent {

    protected myService1: MyService1;
    protected myService2: MyService2;
    protected myService3: MyService3;

    constructor(@Inject(Injector)public injector: Injector) {
        this.myService1 = injector.get(MyService1);
        this.myService2 = injector.get(MyService2);
        this.myService3 = injector.get(MyService3);
    }
}
```

`@Inject` allow you to not have constructor on childs.

And have childs:

```
export class MyComponent extends BaseComponent {
    constructor(public injector: Injector) {
        super(injector);
    }
    ...
}
```

or

```
export class MyComponent extends BaseComponent {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you do this without injector as well? i.e. `@Inject(MyService1)` ? Injector is avoid as much as possible. How does the last one work is that some typescript magic?

Comment: The last one only works because of `@Inject(Injector)`. If you don't want to use that, you must use `super(injector);`

Comment: I personally use Injector in `BaseComponent` and `BaseService` classes because it allow you to add dependencies in them without any refactoring. So it's mainly a use case of `Injector` for me.

Comment: So this must work for `constructor(@Inject() public myService1: MyService1, @Inject() public myService2: MyService2, @Inject() public myService3: MyService3)` ?

Comment: You are right, but if you need more deps in one of your child, you have to give each of them in `super` instead of a single deps `Injector`

Comment: How do you unit test your components without a constructor that accepts the dependencies ? Also, don't you need the services to be available in the constructor?

Comment: first: constructor is to construct, not to use. use services into your `ngOnInit`, second: you must call `super` if you have a constructor, and third: add your services or a mock of your services into your `TestBed.configureTestingModule(...)`

Comment: Yeah, that' what I mean, construct other stuff. The moment you construct other stuff you need a constructor and then you need a super call and then you need to pass your dependencies to the base class anyway ?

Comment: Yes, exactly like in my answer. But if we use your way, inject each services separately, and want an other service into our parent, we need to refactor each childs. Nothing to change in childs using `Injector`

Comment: Right, I do see your point. I'm not 100% sold but I will experiment with this.

Answer (score -1):

No. You can define it in a super class and consume it, but injection has to happen in the class/component being instantiated.

```
class ComponentBase {

  constructor(protected service: SomeService) { }
}

class MyComponent extends ComponentBase {

  constructor(service: SomeService) { super(service) }

  doSomething() {
    this.service.doSomething()
  }
}
```

As you see, there is no real benefit.

**Edit**:  A workaround has been presented that significantly reduces boilerplate by passing the injector instead of the dependencies. In my opinion this is bad practice and violates the [explicit dependencies principle](https://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/). The explicit dependencies principle states that a class or method needs to explicitly specify the dependencies it requires to accomplish it's objective. By passing an injector instead of the actual dependencies you are not specifying the dependencies as explicit. In fact, there is no definition whatsoever of the dependencies that the class requires. This allows the class to call on an arbitrary number of services from within different execution paths, there is no control over what it uses and what it doesn't.

Dependency Injection done right has two forms. Inject into the constructor parameter or inject into the method parameter. This is explicit, controllable, maintainable and type safe.

While it is true that it is more code to write. That more code will save you from a lot of headaches down the line. And keep your classes readable. When passing an injector, no one knows what your class uses or doesn't.